# How to Choose Hosting for SAAS (Software_as_a_service‎) Products

Tags: cloud, web-hosting, saas

Currently I am working on Application for Conducting Online Test Series [A Saas Product]

Any suggestions for selecting hosting, as there will be large no of concurrent requests to server while online exams will be conducted.

How to determine whether server can serve for n number of read/write requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load test your application. For this use JMeter or [BlazeMeter](http://blazemeter.com/).
 Analyse the result particularly from Latency and Response time with lot of users for long time. 
Here is report summary of an Application deployed on PaaS [App42PaaS](https://paashq.shephertz.com). Load test was run with Blazemeter. As latency is very low less than 10 milliseconds from beginning to end and it is not increasing as users are increasing , it indicates that Application will work even if it is loaded for long time. It clearly indicates good performance of application.
Larger latency and response time will show that performance of application is poor.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could build your SaaS on the top of a PaaS, where you could easily scale up/down -horizontally or vertically- your instance so as to get the performance you want in the period of time you would like. Some PaaS let you auto-scale your instance depending on some parameters like the number of requests (see [here](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Autoscaling+explained)).

To determinate how much your server can serve, you should use a load testing tool like BlazeMeter. A similar approach about what you are looking for is this [webinar](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cC0YdvNVQA8), which could give you an idea about how to do the set-up and what results you can expect.

Answer (score 0):

As you said there will be high traffic on your application while the online test is going on, In that case you should deploy your application on PaaS. Where you get the flexibility to scale and descale (Both Vertical or Horizontal ) your app in minutes.

To test the server request and response use JMeter or BlazeMeter and make sure your server is not showing symptoms of overload.

- Requests should be served within 1 second to 30 seconds.
- The web server should not returns an HTTP error code, such as 500, 502, 503, 504, 408, or even 404, which is inappropriate for an overload condition.
- The web server should not refuses or resets (interrupts) TCP connections before it returns any content.